# Why is this query not working when put into a larger query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

[Query 1](https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/IbuTnL) shows that the chemical element "americium" was named after "Americas" which was named after "Amerigo Vespucci".

[Query 2](https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/HOQx9b) shows chemical elements with some information about them. "americium" is part of the output and has number 95.

Now, [Query 3](https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/faSMpg) combines the previous two queries by outputting who/what the chemical elements were named after (directly or indirectly).

Why is only "Americas" listed here for americium but not "Amerigo Vespucci"?
For Samarium with number 62, a direct ("samarskite-(Y)") and indirect ("Vasili Samarsky-Bykhovets") entity are output.

The same problem happens with the elements berkelium and livermorium.

EDIT: The more I think about it it seems to be a problem with the query engine.

---

Query 1:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?named_after ?named_after_name WHERE {
  wd:Q1872 wdt:P138/wdt:P138? ?named_after .
  ?named_after @en@rdfs:label ?named_after_name .
}
```

Query 2:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?Z ?element_name ?element_symbol ?element_discovery WHERE {
  ?chemical_element wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q11344 .
  ?chemical_element wdt:P1086 ?Z .
  ?chemical_element wdt:P246 ?element_symbol .
  ?chemical_element wdt:P575 ?time_of_discovery_or_invention .
  BIND(YEAR(?time_of_discovery_or_invention) AS ?element_discovery)
  ?chemical_element @en@rdfs:label ?element_name .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?Z)
```

Query 3:

```
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?Z ?element_name ?element_symbol ?element_discovery ?named_after ?named_after_name WHERE {
  ?chemical_element wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q11344 .
  ?chemical_element wdt:P1086 ?Z .
  ?chemical_element wdt:P246 ?element_symbol .
  ?chemical_element wdt:P575 ?time_of_discovery_or_invention .
  BIND(YEAR(?time_of_discovery_or_invention) AS ?element_discovery)
  # Here, we add the "named after" information
  ?chemical_element wdt:P138/wdt:P138? ?named_after .
  # Names / Labels
  ?chemical_element @en@rdfs:label ?element_name .
  ?named_after @en@rdfs:label ?named_after_name .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?Z)
```

Comment: Your query seems to work as expected on https://query.wikidata.org/ (after removing the `@en@` syntax, and replacing it with `lang()` filters).

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. Yes, I also noticed, that replacing the "?" path operator by a UNION construct helped. I already notified the developers of the engine.